# Overlay Text Image to A Dirty Background Image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have two images: an image with a text and an image as the dirty background.

Clean Image

[image]

Dirty Background Image

[image]

How will I overlay the clean image to the dirty background image using Python? Please assume that the clean image has the smaller size compared to the dirty background image.

Comment: Tell us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a library called `pillow` (which is a fork of `PIL`) that can do this for you. You can play around with the placements a little, but I think it looks good.

```
# Open your two images
cleantxt = Image.open('cleantext.jpg')
dirtybackground = Image.open('dirtybackground.jpg')

# Convert the image to RGBA
cleantxt = cleantxt.convert('RGBA')
# Return a sequence object of every pixel in the text
data = cleantxt.getdata()

new_data = []
# Turn every pixel that looks lighter than gray into a transparent pixel
# This turns everything except the text transparent
for item in data:
    if item[0] >= 123 and item[1] >= 123 and item[2] >= 123:
        new_data.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        new_data.append(item)

# Replace the old pixel data of the clean text with the transparent pixel data
cleantxt.putdata(new_data)
# Resize the clean text to fit on the dirty background (which is 850 x 555 pixels)
cleantxt.thumbnail((555,555), Image.ANTIALIAS)
# Save the clean text if we want to use it for later
cleantxt.save("cleartext.png", "PNG")
# Overlay the clean text on top of the dirty background
## (0, 0) is the pixel where you place the top left pixel of the clean text
## The second cleantxt is used as a mask
## If you pass in a transparency, the alpha channel is used as a mask
dirtybackground.paste(cleantxt, (0,0), cleantxt)
# Show it! 
dirtybackground.show()
# Save it!
dirtybackground.save("dirtytext.png", "PNG")
```

Here's the output image:
[image]